# strapi API: curl examples for searching

Tags: strapi

Can someone give me some simple curl examples for how to use the strapi API?

For example I can fetch items of a content type like this:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:1337/products
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:1337/products/1
```

But how can I search for specific fields? I saw in the docs that there is a way to query for other fields than `ID`, like e.g. `name` of `products`. But what's the right URL syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all params here: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#api-parameters

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:1337/products?name=somename
```

Answer (score 1):

One more thing that could be useful. 
If your strapi model name has a number or capital letter then strapi will add **"-"** inside of the name.

Model name example:

`model_name1_example`

The same model name, but inside of the strapi:

`model-name-1-examples`

Here you cand find what url/model name do strapi convert you model name for:
 `model_name1_example`/api/model_name1_example/config/routes.json

```
  {
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "model-name-1-examples",
  "handler": "model-name-1-examples.find",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
}
```